# Serviço sendo carregando null no controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Ao realizar um post para o meu controller, ao debugar, vi que o serviço o qual carrego no meu construtor, está vindo o tipo null.

Controller:

```
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    private static IUserService _userService;

    public UserController(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }

    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetUserById(long id)
    {
        var user = _userService.GetById(id);
        return Ok(user);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/User/Insert")]
    public IHttpActionResult Insert(User user)
    {
        user.StartDate = DateTime.Now;
        _userService.Register(user);

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Retorno de erro do debbug:

> Controller' não tem um construtor padrão","Exception Type":"System.ArgumentException","StackTrace"

Comment: Você inicializa o `UserController` em algum momento?

Comment: Qual a estratégia de injeção de dependência que você usa?

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza Estava tentando injetar na WebApiConfig.cs, mas foi sem sucesso. Então, é nenhuma.

Comment: Então, sem jeito de dar certo a menos que você declare o tal construtor padrão, tipo assim: `public UserController() : this(new UserServiceImplementation()) { }`

Comment: Dessa forma não funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode inicializar seu serviço no construtor *default* do seu Controller:

```
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    private IUserService _userService;

    public UserController()
    {
        _userService =  new UserService();
    }

    public UserController(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }

    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetUserById(long id)
    {
        var user = _userService.GetById(id);
        return Ok(user);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/User/Insert")]
    public IHttpActionResult Insert(User user)
    {
        user.StartDate = DateTime.Now;
        _userService.Register(user);

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Caso você tenha interesse em utilizar alguma estratégia de injeção de dependência, existem alguns *container's* muito úteis atualmente. Entre eles existem o Unity e Ninject. Abaixo um exemplo de alguém que teve o mesmo problema que você e o caso dele é tratado com Ninject. Segue link: [Ninject para Injeção de Dependência](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462175/mvc-4-web-api-controller-does-not-have-a-default-constructor)